# Deployment template validation failed template parameters 'scriptUrldsc' in the parameters file are not valid they are not present in the original

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm receiving the error mentioned on the subject, and I'm struggling to fix it.
I'm using an ARM template with several nested ARM templates, the deployment is being done using Azure DevOps.

Below the templates.

This first template is the one calling the nested ones:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
  "existingDataFactoryName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Existing Data Factory name"
    }
  },
  "existingDataFactoryResourceGroup": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Existing Data Factory resource group"
    }
  },
  "existingDataFactoryVersion": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Select the existing Data Factory version"
    },
    "allowedValues": [
      "V1",
      "V2"
    ]
  },
  "virtualMachineName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Virtual Machine Name where the runtime will run. Please don't provide the last numbers of the VM E.g: EUWE01PROJNIR "
    }
  },
  "IntegrationRuntimeName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "IR name must be unique in subscription"
    }
  },
  "NodeCount": {
    "type": "int",
    "maxValue": 4,
    "minValue": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "description": "the node count is between 1 and 4."
    }
  },
  "vmSize": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "Standard_A4_v2"
  },
  "adminUserName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "User name for the virtual machine"
    }
  },
  "adminPassword": {
    "type": "securestring",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Password for the virtual machine"
    }
  },
  "existingVirtualNetworkName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Existing vnet name"
    }
  },
  "existingVnetLocation": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Virtual machine will be create in the same datacenter with VNET"
    }
  },
    "existingVnetResourceGroupName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Name of the existing VNET resource group"
    }
  },
  "existingSubnetInYourVnet": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Name of the subnet in the virtual network you want to use"
    }
  },
  "_artifactsLocation": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The base URI where artifacts required by this template are located."
    },
    "defaultValue": "[deployment().properties.templateLink.uri]"
  },
  "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
    "type": "securestring",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The sasToken required to access _artifactsLocation.  When the template is deployed using the accompanying scripts, a sasToken will be automatically generated."
    },
    "defaultValue": ""
  },
  "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Diagnostic storage account name"
    },
    "defaultValue": ""
  },
    "storageAccountNameRG": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Diagnostic Resource Group of the Diagnostic storage account"
    },
    "defaultValue": ""
  },
    "availabilitySetName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Availability Set Name"
    },
    "defaultValue": ""
  }

},
"variables": {
  "delimiters": [
    "-",
    "_"
  ],      

  "prefix": "[split(parameters('IntegrationRuntimeName'), variables('delimiters'))[0]]",
  "vmTemplateLink": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('nested/VMtemplate.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]",
  "irInstallTemplateLink": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('nested/IRInstall.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]",
  "IRtemplateLink": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('nested/IRtemplate.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]",
  "subnetId": "[resourceId(parameters('existingVnetResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('existingVirtualNetworkName'), parameters('existingSubnetInYourVnet'))]",
  "scriptURL": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('gatewayInstall.ps1', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]",
  "scriptURLdsc": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('DscMetaConfigs.ps1', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]"
},
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "name": "nestedTemplate",
    "resourceGroup": "[parameters('existingDataFactoryResourceGroup')]",
    "properties": {
      "mode": "Incremental",
      "templateLink": {
        "uri": "[variables('IRtemplateLink')]",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "existingDataFactoryName": {
          "value": "[parameters('existingDataFactoryName')]"
        },
        "existingDataFactoryVersion": {
          "value": "[parameters('existingDataFactoryVersion')]"
        },
        "IntegrationRuntimeName": {
          "value": "[parameters('IntegrationRuntimeName')]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "name": "[concat('VMtemplate-', copyIndex())]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId(parameters('existingDataFactoryResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'nestedTemplate')]"
    ],
    "copy": {
      "name": "vmcopy",
      "count": "[parameters('NodeCount')]"
    },
    "properties": {
      "mode": "Incremental",
      "templateLink": {
        "uri": "[variables('vmTemplateLink')]",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "virtualMachineName": {
          "value": "[take(concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'0',copyIndex(1)), 15)]"
        },
        "vmSize": {
          "value": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "adminUserName": {
          "value": "[parameters('adminUserName')]"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
          "value": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "existingVnetLocation": {
          "value": "[parameters('existingVnetLocation')]"
        },
        "subnetId": {
          "value": "[variables('subnetId')]"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
          "value": "[parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')]"
        },
        "availabilitySetName": {
        "value":  "[parameters('availabilitySetName')]"
        },
        "storageAccountNameRG": {
          "value":  "[parameters('storageAccountNameRG')]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "name": "[concat('IRInstalltemplate-', copyIndex())]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "vmcopy"
    ],
    "copy": {
      "name": "irinstallcopy",
      "count": "[parameters('NodeCount')]",
      "mode": "serial"
    },
    "properties": {
      "mode": "Incremental",
      "templateLink": {
        "uri": "[variables('irInstallTemplateLink')]",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "existingDataFactoryVersion": {
          "value": "[parameters('existingDataFactoryVersion')]"
        },
        "datafactoryId": {
          "value": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('existingDataFactoryResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'nestedTemplate')).outputs.irId.value]"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
          "value": "[take(concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'0',copyIndex(1)), 15)]"
        },
        "existingVnetLocation": {
          "value": "[parameters('existingVnetLocation')]"
        },
        "scriptUrl": {
          "value": "[variables('scriptURL')]"
        },
        "scriptUrldsc": {
          "value": "[variables('scriptURLdsc')]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

And this one is where "scriptUrldsc" parameter is being used inside of the nested template.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
  "existingDataFactoryVersion": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "datafactoryId": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "virtualMachineName": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "existingVnetLocation": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "scriptUrl": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "scriptUrldsc": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/' ,parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-installGW')]",
    "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
    "location": "[parameters('existingVnetLocation')]",
    "tags": {
      "virtualMachineName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
    },
    "properties": {
      "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
      "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
      "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
      "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
      "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
          "[parameters('scriptURL')]",
          "[parameters('scripturldsc')]"
        ]
      },
      "protectedSettings": {
        "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File gatewayInstall.ps1', if(equals(parameters('existingDataFactoryVersion'), 'V2'), listAuthKeys(parameters('datafactoryId'), '2017-09-01-preview').authKey1, listAuthKeys(parameters('datafactoryId'), '2015-10-01').key1))]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Not sure if this question applies in your case. Is the file at `_artifactsLocation` getting updated and does it have the parameter? I've had situations where I develop the file locally but the storage blob didn't get updated.

Comment: Hi @Stringfellow

Yes, I have the file on the blob.
In this case, the error is mentioning an error related to the parameter.
#[error]InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'scriptUrldsc' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this template are 'existingDataFactoryVersion, datafactoryId, virtualMachineName, existingVnetLocation, scriptUrl'.

Comment: Hi friend, how do you deploy the Arm template in Azure Devops pipelines? What's the result if you deploy the template [locally using Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell#pass-parameter-values) ?

Comment: Hi Lance, it was a noob error, because I was pushing the code to Azure DevOps and I forgot to update it on the blob, so when the artifact variable was pushing the template it was pushing an outdated template. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the ARM template in the storage blob is missing the parameter `scriptUrldsc`. Assuming the parameter `scriptUrldsc` was added recently, perhaps the template has been updated locally to add the parameter but somehow the version in the storage blob did not get updated with the new parameter.

The error message says the ARM template from storage has the following parameters:

```
...
"parameters": {
  "existingDataFactoryVersion": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "datafactoryId": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "virtualMachineName": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "existingVnetLocation": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "scriptUrl": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"variables": {},
...
```

It's difficult for me to debug and know for certain, but double check the ARM template file in the storage blob to ensure it has the additional parameter.

Comment: I was forgetting to update the template on the blob as soon as I did it the parameter was accepted. 
I have added a task to the pipeline to always update the files from the repo to the Blob.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with 'Updated the blob'
I have the same issue and I am just committing my template to devops. From there the DevTestLab task takes over and should push the template file specified in the task (pointing to the checked in new template..)
Which blob are you referring too then?