# Parameter override: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to override parameters in the azure pipeline task AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2, but cannot get it to work.

I get the error:

```
Parameter override: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it 
follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
```

The task is configured like this:

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: Validate ADF Template
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: DataPlatform Deploy SP - Staging
    resourceGroupName: $(RESOURCE_GROUP)
    deploymentMode: Validation
    csmFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/DataFactory_ARM/ARMTemplateForFactory.json
    csmParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/DataFactory_ARM/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json
    overrideParameters: -factoryName "$(DATAFACTORY_NAME)"
      -Storage_01_RCE_accountKey "$(cedl2-key1)"
      -Storage_02_Curated_accountKey "$(curdl2-key1)"
      -Storage_03_LandingZone_connectionString "$(lnzsa-conn-string)"
      -Storage_04_AzFunction_connectionString "$(funcsa-conn-string)"
      -CT-Reload-ST_properties_CT_Customers_reload_parameters_KafkaTopic "dapl-acc-ct-customers"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IT_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-UK_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-RU_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-FR_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-JP_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-IE_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_env "$(ENV)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_dim_account_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id "$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE)"
      -OM-API-ETL-ST_properties_OM_reload_parameters_Env "acc"
```

$(ENV is set as stage variable:
`ENV: acc`

$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE) is set as job variable
`DATABRICKS_CLUSTERID_DEMANDWARE: 1234-123456-abcd123`

I have tried replacing "$(ENV)" with "acc" but. same error.
Also tried adding a single quote before the first key and after the last key.

The full log of the task is available through pastebin as it was to big to paste in here:
https://pastebin.com/gijMthx6

Comment: Hi, Could you try it with `-DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "acc"` instead of `-DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env "$(ENV)"` and share the result here?

Comment: Hi Carlos, that gives the same result.

Comment: Hi @bramvdk, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'DW_Optimove-DE_properties_pl_demandware_dim_product_parameters_env, ... , DW_Optimove-ES_properties_pl_demandware_fact_order_parameters_cluster_id' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this template are 'factoryName, ADF_Pipeline_Database_connectionString, Storage_01_RCE_accountKey, Storage_02_Curated_accountKey, Storage_03_LandingZone_connectionString, Storage_04_AzFunction_connectionString,....'`

The error message says that the ARM template is missing these parameters. You need check your ARM template file.

The error message says the ARM template has the following parameters:

```
...
"parameters": {
  "factoryName": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "ADF_Pipeline_Database_connectionString": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "Storage_01_RCE_accountKey": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "Storage_02_Curated_accountKey": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "Storage_03_LandingZone_connectionString": {
    "type": "string"
  }
  ....
    },
    "variables": {},
    ...
```

You could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-invalid-template#solution-3---parameter-is-not-valid) and [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797459/deployment-template-validation-failed-template-parameters-scripturldsc-in-the) for more details.